# Erro com Electron + Serialport para usar Arduino

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Estou com problemas para rodar uma aplicação feita com Electron, Serialport e Node.Js para fazer comunicação com um Arduino.

Tenho o seguinte erro:

```
App threw an error during load
Error: Uma rotina de inicializa├º├úo da biblioteca de v├¡nculo din├ómico (DLL) falhou.
\\?\c:\teste\node_modules\serialport\build\Release\serialport.node
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:598:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at bindings (c:\teste\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\teste\node_modules\serialport\lib\bindings.js:3:35)
```

Já tentei várias soluções mas nenhuma funcionou até agora, alguém já passou por isso ou conhece outra biblioteca melhor para usar com Arduino e Electron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o erro adicionando no arquivo *package.json* o seguinte trecho: "install": "electron-rebuild". Segue parte do código para futuras consultas:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "install": "electron-rebuild"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esse é causado porque o módulo não vem com os arquivos necessários compilados por padrão...

Apague os arquivos da pasta `node_modules/serialport/build/Release`

Depois execute o comando a seguir no mesmo diretório que esta o package.json

`npm rebuild --runtime=electron --target=1.6.11 --arch=x64 --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell`

Caso esteja utilizando outra versão do electron, é só alterar o `--target`

Comment: Obrigada pela sua resposta. Infelizmente não resolveu o erro.